# Data transmission during ipojo reconfiguration

Tags: java, ipojo

I have a problem relating data transmission between `ipojo` components during reconfiguration.
Here's an example:

- A component `Calcul_1` provides a calculation service to return a value `(a+b)` (ex: `f(a,b)=> (a+b)`)
- A component `Calcul_2` provides a calculation service to return a value `(a*b)` (ex: `f(a,b)=> (a*b)`)

These two components implement the same calculation service (ex: `f`).

- Now, I have a component `CallCalcul` that uses the calculation service of `Calcul_1`. The component `CallCalcul` calls `f(5,6)` in the component `Calcul_1`. Then, the `CallCalcul component` receives the value of 11.

Problem:

1. When `Calcul_1` receives the value `(5,6)` (not yet calculate) from `CallCalcul`, `CallCalcul` reconfigure by changing connector to `Calcul_2`, i.e., it binds to `Calcul_2`. In this case, how can I transmit `(5,6)` from `Calcul_1` to `Calcul_2` and return `(5*6=30)` to `CallCalcul` ?
2. When `Calcul_1` receives the value `(5,6)` (and calculate their, i.e. 5+6=11) from `CallCalcul`, `CallCalcul` reconfigure. In this case, how can I transmit `11` to `Calcul_2` and return this value to `CallCalcul`?

Comment: Have you actually ran into this kind of problem where a service provider changes in the middle of a method, or is it just a scenario you think might happen ? Also, Do you inject your service dependencies with the `Requires` annotation (or equivalent xml) ?

Comment: this is a scenario i am sure it happen. I inject my service dependencies with the    Requires    . Note: Two components    Calcul_1 and    Calcul_2 implement same service. I use filter to change binding of    CallCalcul to service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, ipojo handle synchronization so that this behavior does not happen.

From the [ipojo documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/describing-components/service-requirement-handler.html#aggregate-dependency-with-field-injection) :

> The synchronization is managed by iPOJO. As soon as you are 'touching' a dependency in a method, iPOJO ensure that you will keep these objects until the end of the method. Nested methods will share the same service object set.

So as long as you are in the same method (or a nested method), you know that your service has not been modified since the first time you accessed it (I assume that your call to `f` is synchronous, so tell me if I am wrong). A `Calcul_1` component will not be replaced by a `Calcul_2` in the middle of a method invocation.

However, I guess this also means that if you want the reconfiguration to take effect, you have to reach the end of the method using your service. For instance, if your component launch a thread with a function like :

```
public void run() {
    while(!end) {
        //while this function is running, myService will not change
        int var = myService.f(a,b); 
        // ... do something with the result
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
}
```

If this function keeps running, ipojo will not bind a new service to `myService` even if your filter is modified. You should put the call to the service in another helper method. It will allow ipojo to lock the access to the service while your component is being reconfigured. for instance :

```
public void run() {
    while(!end) {
        // the service may not be the same each time because this function does
        // not directly use the service
        int var = callDynamicService(a,b); 
        // ... do something with the result
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
}

private int callDynamicService(int a, int b) {
    return myService.f(a,b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. But i don't understand why a component sleep, all components pause? although there are not dependencies between them.

Comment: Are you talking about the call to thread.sleep() ? It is just an example of a simplistic loop you may implement in a runnable (the problem I wanted to point out would still happen without it). The components are not "pausing"; I just mean that when method is executing in your component, ipojo ensure that `myService` references the same instance as long as your method has not returned. If you call `myService` twice in the same method you can be sure the calculation service will be the same each time (multiplication or addition, but not one of each).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I agree with you that requiring component will wait to receive result before reconfiguring. I tested by using    Thread.sleep()    as you talked and it lead to another issus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039926/sleep-a-ipojo-component-all-disable. I want create independent components each other. :(

Comment: I re-tried your example but it has the same result. there are not the difference between putting the call to the service in another helper method and not.