# Sleep a iPOJO component, all disable

Tags: java, ipojo

I have a simple question relating to iPOJO.

When a component iPOJO sleeps, all remaining components will also disable although there are not dependencies between them. Why? Here's an example:

Component 1:

```
@Component(name="frame1", immediate=true)
@Instantiate(name="iframe1")
public class Frame1 implements Runnable{

    String str;
    Label lb = new Label();
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    Frame fr;
public void run() {
    fr = new Frame("Frame1");
    fr.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    fr.setSize(230, 200);
    fr.setLocation(900,250);
    fr.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    lb.setText("Result");
    fr.add(lb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Panel pn = new Panel();
    fr.add(pn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pn.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,1,1));
    Button bt = new Button("Printer 1");
    pn.add(bt);
    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                System.out.println("start sleep");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println("stop sleep");
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    fr.setVisible(true);
 }
 @Validate
 public void start() {
     //this.delayService = dls;
     Thread th = new Thread(this);
     th.start();
 }
 @Invalidate
 public void stop() {
     System.out.println("stop");
     fr.setVisible(false);
 }
}
```

Component 2:

```
@Component(name="frame2", immediate=true)
@Instantiate(name="iframe2")
public class Frame2 implements Runnable{

String str;
Label lb = new Label();
TextField tf = new TextField();
Frame fr;
public void run() {
    System.out.println("start component 2");
    fr = new Frame("Frame2");
    fr.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    fr.setSize(230, 200);
    fr.setLocation(900,250);
    fr.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    lb.setText("Result");
    fr.add(lb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Panel pn = new Panel();
    fr.add(pn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pn.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,1,1));
    Button bt = new Button("Printer 2");
    pn.add(bt);
    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("in 2");
        }
    });

    fr.setVisible(true);
}
@Validate
 public void start() throws Exception {
     //this.delayService = dls;
     System.out.println("start thread 2");
     Thread th = new Thread(this);
     th.start();

     //fr.setVisible(true);
 }
 @Invalidate
 public void stop() throws Exception {
     System.out.println("stop");
     fr.setVisible(false);
 }
}
```

Two components are deployed and running. There are two independent components. But I click the "Printer 1" button. "frame1" component is sleeping during 5s. And during these 5 seconds, i can't click "Printer 2" of "frame2" component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an ipojo issue. Swing uses one thread (and only **one** thread) in order to dispatch events such as clicks. When you click your first button, swing runs your `actionPerformed` in this thread. This method puts your thread to sleep for 5 seconds. This means that the thread responsible for event handling cannot do anything during this time. This is why your program does not respond to your second click.

Whenever you have a long computation in swing (and also osgi), it is often a good idea to run your code in a separate thread in order to avoid blocking the execution (here you have a useless `Thread.sleep()` but I guess you could have an http request or anything that may take a long time instead). You should probably use an [executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or anything similar.